# How to create a different AWS EBS Volume from a AWS Snapshot created out of another EBS type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Can we create a snapshot of EBS volume of Type - Gen Purpose SSD and later create a EBS volume of Type  - Provisioned IOPS SSD from that snapshot?

I am thinking to do this to speed up my copy/update/delete operation of data from the snapshot. Depicting the steps below that I would want to take -

***EBS Volume xvdf ( Type: Gen Purpose SSD) -> Create Snapshot S_xvdf -> Create EBS Volume xvdp(Type : Provisioned IOPS SSD) > Select Snapshot S_xvdf > Volume xvdp created -> Attach Volume as another drive > copy/update/delete***

-- In 'thoughts'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new volume, using any volume type, from your snapshot.
Doesn't matter what was the volume type when snapshot was created.

You can also change your volume type without interruption.
You don't need to create a new one just because you need more IOPS or throughput.
But you can only change it once at every 6 hours.

There is a good youtube video called "**Deep Dive on Amazon EBS Elastic Volumes - 2017 AWS Online Tech Talks**".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

Created a 3TB IOPS SSD volume from 1TB Gen Purpose SSD Snapshot.

When we does modifications to Volume - status is shown as "Available - Optimizing x%" in Orange.

--In 'thoughts'...